# How to compare in a for loop the current index value with the next index value?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, indexing

I have an array like this: [(x1, y1, x2, y2), (x1, y1, x2, y2), (x1, y1, x2, y2), (x1, y1, x2, y2)], and my code is:

```
def draw_lines(image, lines, color=[255, 0, 0], thickness=2, make_copy=True):

if make_copy:
    image = np.copy(image) 
cleaned = []

for line in lines:
    for x1,y1,x2,y2 in line:

        if abs(x2-x1) <=10 and abs(y2-y1) >=19 and abs(y2-y1) <= 70 :
            cleaned.append((x1,y1,x2,y2))
            cv2.line(image, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), color, thickness)
print(" No lines detected: ", len(cleaned))
print (cleaned)
return image
```

In the if statement I would like to add a new "and" criterion, which compare the array current x1 value with the array next x1 value. For example: x1[i+1]-x1[i] > 10

How to use the index, and the iteration int this case?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for `for ind in range(len(lines)):` gives you 4 loops since there are four tuples in the list. So `line[0]` is the first tuple and `lines[0][0]` is `x1`

So to produce x1[i+1]-x1[i] is

```
for ind in range(len(lines)):

    if ind < len(lines): #Ensures no out of bounds
        if lines[ind+1][0]-lines[ind][0] < 10:
            #Do something
        else:
            #Greater or equal to 10
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
for line, next_line in zip(lines, lines[1:]):
```

or if you want to access the individual coordinates as separate variables:

```
for (x1, y1, x2, y2), (x1_, y1_, x2_, y2_) in zip(lines, lines[1:]):
```

Note the loop will stop at the last-but-one position in the list.

Answer (score -1):

I am not the best at this stuff but here is a website i think you should check out that will hopefully help you:

https://www.fluentcpp.com/2018/10/26/how-to-access-the-index-of-the-current-element-in-a-modern-for-loop/